# How can I get rid of acceleration whine?

Tags: noise, accord, acceleration

I have a 2006 Honda Accord Ex 2.4 (4 cyl), which I've maintained pretty well at 150,000 miles. I have no issues with it. The only thing that gets me rattled is a constant whine that's dependent on RPM after 40 mph speed it begins. Only when I press the gas.  As soon as I release the gas pedal it's gone.

What I know for sure:

- in neutral, if I rev up to higher RPMS, no noise
- noise appears to be coming from the center part of the engine
- it is not electronic interference humm

I'm starting to think it's the transmission, but I have no issues from it.

Comment: To eliminate the transmission, put the vehicle in neutral and rev the engine to the appropriate rev range. If you have noise, it's probably not the trans.